# selective PDF split based on the page content

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am looking to split a parent PDF into child PDFs based on the current page text. If page x contains text 'ABC' only then I would split that PDF. However the code with splitter starts from 1st page of PDF.

```
 String currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);
            if (currentPageText.contains(searchText))
            {
                System.out.println("Current page"+page);
                splitter.split(new FileOutputStream("H:/Work/PDFs/Purchase & Sale Activity____" + page + ".pdf"), 200000);
            }
```

Comment: Change the question to reflect that you want to extract pages, rather than splitting the document.

Comment: Goutham, do I understand your comment to @Joris' answer correctly, that you actually want to replace a page with ABC by two pages, one with the content up to ABC, one with the content following the ABC, and then split the document between these page pairs?

Comment: If a page(ex: page 3) contains text "ABC" out of 10 page pdf, then only page 3 should be a new pdf at a destination location.

Answer (score 0):

I would split this problem into parts.
Start by figuring out which pages contain the query String.
You can use ITextExtractionStrategy (or rather a class that implements it) for that purpose.

```
private List<Integer> determineSplitRanges(File inputFile)
{   
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
    List<Integer> splitPages = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<=pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();i++)
    {
        String txt = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfDocument.getPage(i));
        if(txt.contains("ABC")
        {
            splitPages.add(i);
        }
    }
    pdfDocument.close();
}
```

Then split the document based on that information.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
List<PdfDocument> splitDocuments = new PdfSplitter(pdfDocument) {
    int partNumber = 1;
    @Override
    protected PdfWriter getNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange) {
    try {
        return new PdfWriter(destFolder + "splitDocument1_" + String.valueOf(partNumber++) + ".pdf");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}}.splitByPageNumbers(l);

// close sub-documents
for (PdfDocument doc : splitDocuments)
    doc.close();

// close master document
pdfDocument.close();
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: splitByPageNumbers(l) splits into multiple PDFs based on the page no. Example: If I have text "ABC" on page 3 and page 30, then it splits 3 PDFs _page 1 to 3_ , _page 3 to 30_ and _page 30 to end_  . **I am looking to have only page 3 and 30 split where I have my search text**

Comment: Then you don't want to split a pdf, you want to extract some pages based on a search criterium.
Re-word your question.